# How to use a pipe in two different Angular Modules

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pipe

I have a pipe

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
  .....
    return keys;
  }
}
```

I have two modules in which I need to use this. If I do something like this in both the modules, I get an error saying that "two modules declare KeysPipe"

Module1, Module2:

```
declarations: [KeysPipe],
```

I then tried exporting KeysPipe through it's own module so that I can import it in to the two modules in which I need to use it

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ KeysPipe],
})
export class KeysPipeModule {
}
```

Now I'm importing the KeysPipeModule in the two modules I need to use KeysPipe

Module1, Module2:

```
imports: [KeysPipeModule],
```

But now I get a different template error saying that the pipe isn't found "The pipe 'keys' could not be found ("v *ngIf="docalc">"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're on the right track the only thing your code is missing is the export in the `KeysPipeModule`. This is what it should look like:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ KeysPipe],
    exports: [KeysPipe]
})
export class KeysPipeModule {}
```